# How to append JSON looking string to HTML pre tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a part of page looking like this:

[image]

And here is how it should look:
[image]

Now I'm retrieving from database all data that I need to show on page.

```
$korisnickiId=$_POST['userId'];
$q="SELECT `facebook_app_id`,`facebook_ids`,`authorization_date`,`status`,`date_added`,`users_added` FROM `previous_imports` WHERE `user_id`='$korisnickiId'";
$result=$mysqli->query($q);
while($fetchedResult=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
$encoded = $fetchedResult;
$makeItApliable='{';
foreach($encoded as $key=>$value){
$makeItApliable.='
"'.$key.'" : "'.$value.'",
';
}
$makeItApliable.='},';
rtrim($makeItApliable, ",");
echo ($makeItApliable);
}
```

So `$makeItApliable` after this chunk of code looks like this:
[image]
And I want it to look exactly like this on page, so I'm echoing `$makeItApliable` variable and running this part of `jQuery` code(everything is done via `Ajax`):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "../includes/adapter.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: data,
      async: true,
      success: function (data) {
      if(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#goliSpan').html("<span>"+data+"</span>");
               }
      }
 });
```

And this is `HTML` where this data should be appended:

```
<pre id="istosakriti" class="">
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: <span class="plavi-txt">GET, POST</span>
Content-Type: <span class="plavi-txt">application/json</span>
Vary: <span class="plavi-txt">Accept</span>
        <span id="goliSpan" class="tamnocrveno"></span>
</pre>
```

So in this span whose id is `goliSpan` this JSON(or JSON looking string) should be appended. But When I run code above nothing happens. Even tried:

```
$('#goliSpan').append("<span>"+data+"</span>");
```

And

```
$('#goliSpan').text(data);
```

But nothing works. If you have any idea, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `json_encode` to encode `$result` and set `Content-Type`, update your PHP code:

```
$korisnickiId=$_POST['userId'];
$q="SELECT `facebook_app_id`,`facebook_ids`,`authorization_date`,`status`,`date_added`,`users_added` FROM `previous_imports` WHERE `user_id`='$korisnickiId'";
$result=$mysqli->query($q);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```